Laravel medialibrary dynamically add component
I'm using laravel-medialibrary-pro v2.7.3 and livewire v2.12.8 to make a form page for a content management system. I have two Laravel models: Partner and PartnerDocument in a one-to-many relationship. The PartnerDocument model contains some additional data for the file that is associated with it, so this model uses the Spatie\MediaLibraryPro\Http\Livewire\Concerns\WithMedia trait.
I've tried the example here and wondered how to apply it in a situation where the x-media-library-collection has to be created dynamically. My idea was to use an "Add" button that does the following:

in MyForm class:


generate a random unique string $key, append it to $this->keys array
create custom properties: $this->{'partner_document_' . $key} of type PartnerDocument and $this->{'media_' . $key}
add 'media_' . $key to $this->mediaComponentNames


in MyForm's component blade template:

@foreach ( $keys as $key )
    @php
        $model = 'partner_document_' . $key;
        $media = 'media_' . $key;
    @endphp
    <x-media-library-collection
        :name="$media"
        :model="$this->{$model}"
        collection="attachments" />
@endforeach

Lastly, when the submit button is clicked, it calls save method as such:
use Livewire\Component;

class MyForm extends Component {
    ...
    public function save() {
        ...
        foreach ( $this->keys as $key ) {
            $model = 'model_' . $key;
            $media = 'media_' . $key;
            $this->$model->addFromMediaLibraryRequest($this->$media)
                        ->toMediaCollection('attachments');
        }
    }
    ...
}

But the uploaded file cannot be associated with the model. On the media table, it is associated with Spatie\MediaLibraryPro\Models\TemporaryUpload but not PartnerDocument. The property $this->$media is always an empty array. Apparently, only properties declared in the class (not at runtime) whose names are in $this->mediaComponentNames worked.
Edit
A similar question was posted but unanswered. I also posted this question on Spatie Github discussion

If you need to render a component dynamically, you can just use <x-dynamic-component> that comes with laravel.

@IGP thanks for replying, but I don't think it would help. I already know what component to use (<x-media-library-collection> from laravel-medialibrary), it's just I want to create it dynamically, i.e. a component is added every time the user clicks the "Add" button. While the button works, the dynamically-added custom property $this->{'media_' . $key} (whose name is also stored in $this->mediaComponentNames and is used for naming the mentioned component) does not get updated when the user finishes uploading a file, which is not the case if we were to set the property "statically"
